# How to use AsyncTask in an Android app

Tags: android, json, android-asynctask

I am all stuck with the AsyncTask, confused with the params, progress, result should I put. In my application I need to display images 
in the gallery. The url consist of all the images. I am fetching these image urls via JSON and saving the response in an arraylist and pass it to the new
activity. However, I am able to save the JSON response in the arraylist named "image_urls". As Iam new to android, I am confused what params should be 
provided in background and in asynctask. Thanks in advance.

Following is the separate class which I have created, In doInBackground Iam fetching the reuired items using JSON.I am confused what all parameters should I put inside AsyncTask and doInBackground

```
public abstract  class Images1 extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void>{
        private static volatile Executor sDefaultExecutor = SERIAL_EXECUTOR;
        private static String url = "http://www.ttt.com/album_pro/array_to_encode";

         ArrayList<String> urlList = new ArrayList<String>();
         JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
         ArrayList<String> image_urls = new ArrayList<String>();


         protected ArrayList<String>  doInBackground(Void... params) {
                 JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);

                    try{
                JSONObject seo = json.getJSONObject("SEO");
                JSONArray folio = seo.getJSONArray("Folio");

                JSONArray image_urls1 = new JSONArray();
                String s1=seo.getString("Folio");

                                for(int i=0;i<folio.length();++i)
                                {
                            String m = folio.getString(i);
                            Log.v("M"+i,m);
                            image_urls.add(m+ ",");

                                }
                    }
                    catch(Exception e)
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
               return image_urls;
             }

             protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {

             }


             protected void onPostExecute(String[] result) {

             }

    }
```

Comment: Refer [this](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-multilevel-listview-tutorial/) example

Comment: read about AsyncTask's generic types http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
    public class GetTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Integer> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        mPreogressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(Mainactivity.this,
                "Loading", "Please wait");
    }

    @Override
    protected Integer doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //Do your stuff here call ur methods
                    imagedownload();
        return 0;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (mPreogressDialog.isShowing())
            mPreogressDialog.dismiss();


    }

}

public vlid imagedownload(){
JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);

                try{
            JSONObject seo = json.getJSONObject("SEO");
            JSONArray folio = seo.getJSONArray("Folio");

            JSONArray image_urls1 = new JSONArray();
            String s1=seo.getString("Folio");

                            for(int i=0;i<folio.length();++i)
                            {
                        String m = folio.getString(i);
                        Log.v("M"+i,m);
                        image_urls.add(m+ ",");

                            }
                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you see on http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html they have explained AsyncTask very nicely.

But if you don't get it, let me give it a try:

Android modifies the user interface via one thread, the so called **UI Thread**. If you perform a long running operation directly on the UI Thread, for example downloading a file from the internet, the user interface of your application will “**freeze**” until the corresponding task is finished.

***AsyncTask*** *enables proper and easy use of the UI thread. This class allows to perform background operations and publish results on the UI thread without having to manipulate threads and/or handlers.*

In order to use the AsyncTask class, you must extend it and override at least the doInBackground() method.

The most common methods you will need to implement are these:

1. `onPreExecute()` – called on the UI thread before the thread starts running. This method is usually used to setup the task, for example by displaying a progress bar.
2. `doInBackground(Params…)` – this is the method that runs on the background thread. In this method you should put all the code you want the application to perform in background. When it finishes, it sends the result to the onPostExecute().
3. `onProgressUpdate()` - called when you invoke publishProgress() in the doInBackground().
4. `onPostExecute(Result)` – called on the UI thread after the background thread finishes. It takes as parameter the result received from doInBackground().

`AsyncTask` is a generic class, it uses 3 types: `AsyncTask<Params, Progress, Result>.`

`Params` – the input. what you pass to the AsyncTask (it can be the URL from where file will be downloaded)

`Progress` – if you have any updates, passed to onProgressUpdate() (This argument is used if you want to show progress of the downloading process on UI)

`Result` – the output. what returns doInBackground() to onPostExecute()